# Eliminating characters within columns R

Tags: r, dataframe, types

I have a dataframe with a column as follows:

```
x = data.frame("A" = c("93 VLC", "43 VLC", "73 VLC"))
```

I am trying to modify the column "A" to eliminate the "VLC" and just keep the number.

I would like the output to be:

```
x = data.frame("A" = c(93, 43, 73))
```

Is there a way to do this? thanks

Comment: If you want to just remove "VLC" ddi you try `sub('\\sVLC', '', x$A)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to extract the numeric part, use `parse_number`

```
x$A <- readr::parse_number(x$A)
x$A
#[1] 93 43 73
```

---

Or using `trimws`

```
as.numeric(trimws(x$A, whitespace = "\\D+"))
#[1] 93 43 73
```

---

Or using `sub`

```
as.numeric(sub("\\s*\\D+$", "", x$A))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_remove() from the stringr library:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

x = data.frame("A" = c("93 VLC", "43 VLC", "73 VLC"))

x %>%
  mutate(A = str_remove(A, ' VLC'))

#   A
# 1 93
# 2 43
# 3 73
```